# Why React Native FlatList style not change with state

Tags: react-native, styles

I have some tabs. I want to change the color of the selected tab. I created a state for selected tab index which will hold the tab ID. When Tab is pressed the selected state change to the pressed tab ID. I am comparing the selected state to tab ID. If  both are equal then the selected tab will have some different style.

**But when state changes and condition is true, the selected tab is not changing its state.**  **Why change in state do not trigger the comparison in the style to update the style?**

```js
<FlatList 
  horizontal
  data={this.state.drinkgroup}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  renderItem={({item, index}) =>
  {
    return  <Tab 
      item={item} 
      selected={this.state.selected}           
      changeSelected={
        () => {
          this.setState({selected: item.id}, function(){                       console.log(this.state.selected, item.id)
          console.log(this.state.selected==item.id)
          })
        }} 
      }
  }
/>
```

```js
export const Tab = ({item, selected, changeSelected}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.tabStyle, (selected==item.id)? styles.tabSelectedStyle: null]}
            onPress={changeSelected}
            underlayColor='#fff'
        >
            <Text style={{color: '#f2f2f2', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 15}}>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tabStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#800080',
        height: 32,
        paddingRight: 15,
        paddingLeft: 15
    },
    tabSelectedStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: 'white', 
        borderBottomWidth: 3
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing extraData={this.state} to `FlatList` we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

```
<FlatList
   data={this.props.data}
   extraData={this.state}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
```

This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow- equal.

Make sure that everything your renderItem function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes.

This includes the data prop and parent component state.

More Details :- [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `extraData` prop to the Flatlist, if you want it to re render its items. You can do it like `extraData={this.state}`.

By passing `extraData={this.state}` to `FlatList` we make sure `FlatList` itself will re-render when the `state.selected` changes. Without setting this `extraData` prop, `FlatList` would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.
For further details you can visit [official documentation here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

Comment: I am already proving the selected state as props in Tab component. Please explain further.